# Web server virtual filenames

Tags: apache, iis, web

I am not sure whether this is possible. I need to upload 1 file to web server. Then download this file as multiple parts/chunks with fixed size. In other words, after request for download of `http://my.domain/dir/file123.bin`, the web server has to run some script and give it the URL or only `123` as parameter. The same is possible with: `http://my.domain/dir/?chunk=123` - then `index.php` or `index.aspx` will return chunk #123. Can the same be done with `dir/file123.bin` syntax?

Comment: Google URL rewriting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On apache simply use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^/dir/file([\d]*).bin$  /dir/?chunk=$1 [L,PT]
```

On IIS there is a URL Rewrite extension that seems to do almost the same thing.